# AUTO_INCREMENT implementation for string column containing a special number format

Tags: php, mysql, sql

## Context and goal

In table `clients` I have a column `clientNum CHAR(11) NOT NULL` with `UNIQUE KEY` constraint. It contains client number in the format `xxx-xxx-xxx` where `x` is a decimal digit. For more details on the format see below.

I want to implement something like `AUTO_INCREMENT` for this column so that each client gets their number calculated automatically. From [MySQL `CREATE TABLE` docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html):

> An integer or floating-point column can have the additional attribute `AUTO_INCREMENT`. When you insert a value of `NULL` (recommended) or `0` into an indexed `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, the column is set to the next sequence value. Typically this is `value+1`, where `value` is the largest value for the column currently in the table. `AUTO_INCREMENT` sequences begin with `1`.

So I want to find the next number available and use it as `clientNum` value for newly inserted client row. Next number available is current maximum of `clientNum` incremented.

I’m coding in PHP using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to access the MySQL database (see [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)).

## Client number format

As stated above, the client number is in format `xxx-xxx-xxx` where `x` is a decimal digit. The range of each segment is `000` to `999`. It is basically a 9-digit integer with leading zeroes and dash as thousands separator. It cannot get above `999-999-999`.

Currently we want it be even more restricted, specifically in format `000-1xx-xxx` (between `000-100-000` and `000-199-999`). But there are already some numbers in the database that can start anywhere from `000-000-001` to `500-000-000`.

Unfortunately it has to be stored in this format, I cannot change it.

## Finding maximum

I need to get the max number in range `000-100-000` to `000-199-999`, values outside this range must be ignored. This is where my problem comes in because as said before some numbers already exist above this.

Maximum is never `000-199-999`. Otherwise in would result in adding `000-200-000` and the next time called maximum will be `000-199-999` again, resulting in attempt to insert `000-200-000` again.

## How incrementation works

In PHP in can be done like this:

```
$clientNum = "000-100-000";
$clientNum = str_replace("-", "", $clientNum);
$clientNum++;
$clientNum = implode("-", str_split(str_pad($clientNum, 9, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT), 3));
```

Final `$clientNum` value is `000-100-001`.

When the initial number is `000-120-015` then the code above produces `000-120-016`. Overflow propagates to the next segment, i.e. `000-100-999` becomes `000-101-000`. `999-999-999` cannot be incremented.

## Idea to start with

In a loop I want to get the next number available, check if that number exists in the database, and if so, redo that loop until it finds an unused number. I know how to check if it’s in the database the first time, but I’m not sure how to do the loop.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Does your number start with 0? E.g: 000-123-456, 012-345-678

Comment: @StephanusYanaputra currently we want it to start with 000-100-000, but there are already some numbers in the system that can start anywhere from 000-000-001 to 500-000-000 so just wanting to run a check

Comment: @Palec yes MySQL. I'm coding in PDO though http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: What do u need the max value of each of the three fragments in the format? Is it 999 to limit it to 3-digit? The qstn needs a clarification there.

Comment: @RajeshPaul sorry I don't understand your question?

Comment: There are 3 fragments in the format "000-000-000". What do u need the max value of each of the fragments; Do u want it in the range **000 to 999** for each?

Comment: @RajeshPaul yes the range for each segment will be 000 to 999. So if the number I get back is `000-120-015` then the code above will make that `000-120-016`, check it in the database, and if that number already exists keeping adding until it finds an empty one. Unfortunately it has to be stored in this format

Comment: Are you filling gaps or trying to replicate an identity increment?

Comment: @dpDesignz So should the next value of "000-000-999" be "000-001-999" or "000-001-000"?

Comment: @Palec, exactly, correct! :).

Comment: @dpDesignz I massively edited your question to make it really clear and incorporate all the things discussed in comments. This way it could be useful for future readers – they won’t have to digg through all the comments to get all the information. Please check that I’ve done it right and delete the comments that are not needed anymore. I’ll delete this comment later, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to solve this in SQL, because otherwise you need two transactions (one for reading, one for writing) and meanwhile the number could be used by a concurrent access.

In MySQL, you can use this SQL reimplementation of your PHP code:

```sql
INSERT(INSERT(LPAD(CAST(CAST(REPLACE(clientNum, '-', '') as UNSIGNED) + 1 as CHAR), 9, '0'), 7, 0, '-'), 4, 0, '-')
```

*This increments `000-000-999` to `000-001-000` and `999-999-999` to `100-000-000` (truncated from `100-000-0000` by `LPAD()`). I warned you.*

E.g. to just preview what the next value is, use

```sql
SELECT INSERT(INSERT(LPAD(CAST(CAST(REPLACE(clientNum, '-', '') as UNSIGNED) + 1 as CHAR), 9, '0'), 7, 0, '-'), 4, 0, '-') FROM clients
```

If you want to use this when inserting a new row, it is used like this:

```sql
INSERT
INTO clients(clientNum, name)
SELECT
    INSERT(INSERT(LPAD(CAST(
        COALESCE(MAX(CAST(REPLACE(clientNum, '-', '') AS UNSIGNED)), 0) + 1
    AS CHAR), 9, '0'), 7, 0, '-'), 4, 0, '-'),
    'John Doe'
FROM clients
```

This works regardless of what API you use to access the database, as long as it is MySQL database. The database does the computation. However, it does not work if `clients` is a temporary table, which I expect it not to be. More on that below.

See also [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html), [CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast), [COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) and [INSERT … SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) in MySQL manual.

---

Later you added that the permitted values are from range `000-100-000` to `000-199-999`. Other values shall be ignored for the purpose of finding maximum. A `WHERE` clause must be added to the `SELECT` part of `INSERT` written above.

```sql
INSERT
INTO clients(clientNum, name)
SELECT
    INSERT(INSERT(LPAD(CAST(
        COALESCE(MAX(CAST(REPLACE(clientNum, '-', '') AS UNSIGNED)), 0) + 1
    AS CHAR), 9, '0'), 7, 0, '-'), 4, 0, '-'),
    'John Doe'
FROM clients
WHERE clientNum BETWEEN '000-100-000' AND '000-199-999'
```

---

Then you stated that my solution does not work for you and [proposed a supposed fix](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3605509):

```sql
INSERT
INTO clients(clientNum, name)
VALUES
    (SELECT
        INSERT(INSERT(LPAD(CAST(
            COALESCE(MAX(CAST(REPLACE(clientNum, '-', '') AS UNSIGNED)), 0) + 1
        AS CHAR), 9, '0'), 7, 0, '-'), 4, 0, '-')
        FROM clients AS tmptable
        WHERE clientNum BETWEEN '000-100-000' AND '000-199-999'),
    'John Doe'
```

This uses a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) instead of the `INSERT … SELECT` syntax.

In MySQL, table cannot be modified (by `INSERT` in this case) and read by a subquery at the same time. Quoting the subquery manual:

> In MySQL, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery. This applies to statements such as [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html), [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert.html), [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html), [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), and (because subqueries can be used in the `SET` clause) [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html).

However, you found a [workaround using a temporary table](http://verysimple.com/2011/03/30/mysql-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/). A temporary table is used when an alias (in this case `clients AS tmptable`) is defined, which evades reading from and writing to the same table at the same time. You used temporary table to store the original table, the article describing the workaround uses it to store the result of the subquery (which is more efficient, I guess). Both approaches work.

At this point I want to point out that my solution should work (and [works for me](http://pastebin.com/X9hsez9Y)!) too except for the improbable case when `clients` is a temporary table. I think I can expect it not to be one. Quoting the `INSERT … SELECT` manual page:

> When selecting from and inserting into a table at the same time, MySQL creates a temporary table to hold the rows from the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) and then inserts those rows into the target table. However, it remains true that you cannot use `INSERT INTO t ... SELECT ... FROM t` when `t` is a `TEMPORARY` table, because `TEMPORARY` tables cannot be referred to twice in the same statement (see [Section C.5.7.2, “`TEMPORARY` Table Problems”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html)).

As for me this is explicitly saying that my original approach using `INSERT … SELECT` should work.

---

Just to provide a complete answer, I’ll address your original request for PHP solution using database polling. Once more I must add that this is certainly not a good solution.

Your `clientNum` column must be a unique key. You need to repeat the following steps until successful update:

1. Get the current maximum of `clientNum`.
2. Increment the obtained value.
3. Try to insert the row.
4. If successful, finish, otherwise throw the `clientNum` max value away and loop.

The insertion will fail due to violation of the aforementioned unique key constraint. This happens when another connection to the database successfully performs an insert in the meantime between steps *1.* and *3.*.

You should prepare the statement outside the loop using [`PDO::prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and then [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) it in the loop. The return value of `execute` method indicates success (`true`) or failure (`false`).

This is enough info to implement step *3.*. Steps *1.* and *2.* consist of fetching the result of

```sql
SELECT MAX(clientNum) FROM clients
```

and running it through the code provided by [Stephanus Yanaputra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603419/2157640). Step *4.* is a simple loop condition using the return value from execution of `INSERT` query in step *3.*.

Comment: thanks for this, I just realised I forgot a crucial bit of information. Due to numbers already being in the system I need to check the MAX() between the values of `000-100-000` to `000-199-999`. Is this possible? Most of these are new to me so not sure what to alter. :)

Comment: Also the `REPLACE(clientNum, '_', '')`, shouldn't that underline be a dash?

Comment: This looks much better! :). Thanks so much! My only query now is for an insert I don't understand how this works? Shouldn't it be `INSERT INTO clients (clientNum, name) VALUES ((//SELECT INSERT HERE),'John Doe')`

Comment: I already linked to the `INSERT … SELECT` syntax from my answer. Now I found there that it shouldn’t work due to temporary tables limitation. But it works for me: http://pastebin.com/X9hsez9Y After your change this solution works too and is definitely correct, thanks for your edit!

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Never worked with `INSERT … SELECT` before so wasn't sure :)

Comment: @dpDesignz Taking back what I said about my original solution. It should work. Edited my answer to provide details and manual references. It should be more efficient and easier to read, too. But your approach works too, despite being quite hacky.

Comment: Now I realized that adding `DEFAULT '000-100-000'` to the `clientNum` column could allow to get rid of the `COALESCE(…, 0)` from the query. This may make it a bit faster.

Comment: I'm wanting to use this again, but now I'm using the date to find a number for the `between` (for example, today it will check as `BETWEEN '014-101-700' AND '014-101-799'`), but I'm getting the error `There was an error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '000-000-001' for key 'stud_swn'` I think this has something to do with the LPAD? Are you able to help please?

Comment: @dpDesignz Sorry, ignore my previous comment if you have already read it. Gave it another thought and the problem is obvious to me now. When no value is found in the given range, 000-000-001 is used as default. Change the second parameter of the `MAX()` call from 0 to `14101699` and you’ll be fine.

Comment: hmm that made the number `014-101-800` and it should have been `014-101-700`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    mysql_connect(....);
    mysql_select_db($db_name);
    $res=mysql_query("select ClientNum from ClientTable");
    $name_arr=array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        foreach($row as $name)
            $name_arr[]=$name;
    }

    $clientNum="000-000-000";
    while(true){
        $clientNum = str_replace("-", "", $clientNum);
        $clientNum++;
        if($clientNum>999999999)
        {
                echo("No mismatch found");
                break;
        }
        $clientNum = implode("-", str_split($clientNum, 3));
        if(!in_array($clientNum, $name_arr))
        {
                echo "The first unmatched clientNum is:".$clientNum;//This is what you want.
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

### Comments

1. The query execution only once i.e. outside the `while` loop makes it less time complex. The time complexity is reduced due to use of array instead of execution of the query itself multiple times because searching in an array is comparatively very less time complex than searching in the database.

Comment: Fetching all the client numbers to the application is a bad idea – it could be a lot of data, therefore very slow. The maximum can be found server-side very easily.

Comment: @Palec Its not about finding the **maximum** but about sorting it. Can you suggest how to sort a string attribute in the particular format. Now can you suggest a `SELECT` query with a resultset sorted on `clientNum`? Then your logic will be appreciable.

Comment: @Palec I have already specified Why it is better to run a single query though with larger return value than to run a query each time the loop iterates if you are really concerned about the **time-complexity**.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you are doing. You’re looking for the smallest value available. “Next number available” (as OP asked) is maximum plus one in the DB world. As far as sorting is concerned… Your algorithm does not work without sorted `clientNum`. Add `ORDER BY clientNum` at the end of your `SELECT` query. If sorting only by the last three chars is desired, use `ORDER BY RIGHT(clientNUm, 3)`. Your algorithm is more complicated to implement in SQL, still I would do it (using stored procedure) to evade the need for huge data transfers and polling.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution based on function that you provided.
Change the function name **rawr()** to any naming that you like. (I couldn't find the best name and ended up using some gibberish name lol).

```
function rawr($in)
{
    $num = str_replace("-", "", $in);
    $num++;

    // Convert back
    $str = (string) $num;

    // Add Leading 0
    while(strlen($str) < 9)
    {
        $str = "0" . $str;
    }
    echo $str . "<br />";
    $final = substr($str,0,3) . "-" . substr($str,3,3) . "-" . substr($str,6,3);

    return $final;
}
```

To test it, try this code:

```
echo rawr(0);
echo "<br />";
echo rawr("000-000-000");
echo "<br />";
echo rawr("012-345-678");
echo "<br />";
echo rawr("123-456-789");
echo "<br />";
```

This will give an output that you desire. However you will have to code it yourself to test the database. In my opinion, this is not the best way to solve your problem, but it should work :)

Comment: Adding leading zeroes could be done via [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)`($str, 9, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)` or [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)`('%09d', $num)`.

Comment: And OP-proposed `$final = implode('-', str_split($str, 3));` is IMO more readable and probably faster (less function calls) than your use of `substr` and concatenation.